# Why does Union of types not resolve to the constrained generic type in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I have the following example.

```
from typing import Union, TypeVar, Dict, Sequence

IdentifierSymbol = TypeVar("IdentifierSymbol", str, int)

def f(ids: Sequence[IdentifierSymbol]) -> Dict[int, IdentifierSymbol]:
    return dict(zip(range(len(ids)), ids))


def g(ids: Union[Sequence[int], Sequence[str]]) -> int:
    x = f(ids)
    return 1
```

PyLance (I guess using mypy inside) complains with the following in the line `x=f(ids)`:

```
Argument of type "Sequence[int] | Sequence[str]" cannot be assigned to parameter "ids" of type "Sequence[IdentifierSymbol@f]" in function "f"
  Type "Sequence[int] | Sequence[str]" cannot be assigned to type "Sequence[IdentifierSymbol@f]"
    TypeVar "_T_co@Sequence" is covariant
      Type "str" is not compatible with constrained type "int" PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

I am not sure how to interpret this, but it sounds like the problem is that int is not compatible with str. But why is this an issue in this case? I have either a sequence of strs or a sequence of ints, where does the compatibility between int and str come in?

Comment: Note that mypy fails with a different error here: ``Value of type variable "IdentifierSymbol" of "f" cannot be "object"``. IIRC MyPy resolves a variable that can be inhabited by two types via the supertype instead of Union.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does mypy infer the common base type instead of the union of all contained types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452652/why-does-mypy-infer-the-common-base-type-instead-of-the-union-of-all-contained-t)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Huh I guess PyLance has its own type checker then. Surprised about that. It could well be that Union[Sequence[int], Sequence[str]] resolves to Sequence[object] or something like that and then doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for `mypy`, then in the current version (0.800), this does not work due to the peculiarities of deducing type variables ([`TypeVar`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id19)): when its type is deduced from multiple types (including used in `Union` and `Sequence`), it is reduced to their closest common base type. In this case, there will be an error when this common base type is not included in the TypeVar constraint list.

This behavior [may change](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8586) in future versions.

For example:

```
class A: ...

class B(A): ...

class C(A): ...

T = TypeVar("T")

def foo(var1: T, var2: T) -> T:
    return var1
    
reveal_type(foo(B(), C()))  # Revealed type is 'main.A*'

def bar(var: T) -> T:
     return var

def baz(var: Union[A, B]):
    reveal_type(bar(var))  # Revealed type is 'main.A*'

def qux(var: Sequence[T]) -> T:
    return var[0]

def quux(var: Tuple[A, B]):
    reveal_type(qux(var))  # Revealed type is 'main.A*'

def quuux(var: Union[Sequence[A], Sequence[B]]):
    reveal_type(qux(var))  # Revealed type is 'main.A*'
```

You need to use other type annotations, for example make `g` function also generic. Perhaps someone will suggest a more elegant solution.

```
def g(ids: Sequence[IdentifierSymbol]) -> int:
    x = f(ids)
    return 1
```

Comment: Oh that's interesting, so basically my Union[Sequence[int], Sequence[str]] basically becomes Sequence[object] or some such? Bizarre. It looks like this also happens if I overload the initial function instead of using TypeVar, so I guess Union is doing some weird stuff? Sadly PyLance doesn't like it if I use TypeVar only once in the function signature. But it does make the type warning in the function body go away.

Comment: "Sadly PyLance doesn't like it if I use TypeVar only once in the function signature." This rule is somewhat obscure for me. I would disable it by `# type: ignore`