# How to fix mypy inferring loop variable as "object"?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, mypy

I made this simple function which I want to check with mypy and
pylint.  It just parses a string and converts it to the appropriate
type.

```py
import re
from typing import Any, Callable
    
def parse_constant(constant: str) -> Any:
    for reg, get_val in [
            (re.compile(r'\'(.*)\''), str),
            (re.compile(r'true', re.IGNORECASE), lambda _: True),
            (re.compile(r'false', re.IGNORECASE), lambda _: False),
            (re.compile(r'([0-9]+)'), int),
            (re.compile(r'([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'), float)
    ]:
        match = reg.fullmatch(constant)
        if match is not None:
            if len(match.groups()) == 0:
                val = None
            else:
                val = match.groups()[0]
            return get_val(val)
    return None
```

It works fine but mypy complains: I get `error: "object" not callable`
at line 18 (`return get_val(val)`).

Now if I replace, `str` by `lambda x: str(x)` mypy is happy but pylint
complains with `Lambda may not be necessary`.

What is the proper way to fix that?

Comment: The cause of this is that MyPy selects the *base* instead of the *union* when mixing types via inference. The base of ``type`` and ``Callable`` is ``object``. Might be relevant: [Why does mypy infer the common base type instead of the union of all contained types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452652/why-does-mypy-infer-the-common-base-type-instead-of-the-union-of-all-contained-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that MyPy must infer `get_val` from a mixture of `Callable` and `Type`. In this case, [MyPy selects the *base* instead of the *union* of the types.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452652/why-does-mypy-infer-the-common-base-type-instead-of-the-union-of-all-contained-t) Explicitly annotate the types to avoid too broad inference.

Inside the `for` loop, only the loop variables can be annotated. By moving the iterable outside the loop, it can be annotated:

```py
import re
from typing import Any, Callable, Pattern, List, Tuple

cases: List[Tuple[Pattern[str], Callable]] = [
    (re.compile(r'\'(.*)\''), str),
    (re.compile(r'true', re.IGNORECASE), lambda _: True),
    (re.compile(r'false', re.IGNORECASE), lambda _: False),
    (re.compile(r'([0-9]+)'), int),
    (re.compile(r'([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'), float)
]

def parse_constant(constant: str) -> Any:
    for reg, get_val in cases:
        match = reg.fullmatch(constant)
        if match is not None:
            if len(match.groups()) == 0:
                val = None
            else:
                val = match.groups()[0]
            return get_val(val)
    return None
```

Moving the cases outside of the function has the added advantage that they are created only once. This is especially of importance for `re.compile`, which is now compiled once and then stored for repeated use.

Comment: Many thanks for the clear answer (and for providing a clearer question title)! Nevertheless I'm a bit confused about this: mypy complains because basically`str` is not a `Callable` but if I tell him explicitly that it's a `Callable` then he's ok with that.  I guess the lesson is to rely on explicit typing when I face this situation. Thanks again.

Comment: @qouify I am afraid that is not obvious indeed. The root problem is that inference has multiple choices, such as the literal ``str`` being of type ``Type[str]`` or ``Callable[..., str]``, and has to pick *one*. Notably, once inference has made a selection this is "locked in" even if it leads to conflicts later on. By providing an annotation at a point before inference has "locked in", you can influence which choice is made.

Comment: I see.  I'm probably not familiar enough with the typing mechanism and I guess I should learn more on that to properly use mypy.  At first, my assumption was that there is some inheritance mechanism between types in such a way that `Type[str]` inherits from `Callable` but that's obviously a mistake. Thanks for your help.