# Use union of arg types instead of supertype for generic variadic function

Tags: python, variadic-functions, mypy, typechecking

I have a generic function `one_of` that may return any of its (variable) arguments. Its return type may be the supertype of all of its arguments; however, I'd like to annotate its usage locations with the *union* of their types instead.

```py
from typing import TypeVar
import random


T = TypeVar("T")


def one_of(*args: T) -> T:
    return random.choice(args)


def int_or_str() -> int | str:
    return one_of(1, "one")
```

This is the error mypy provides:

```
vararg_type.py:11: error: Incompatible return value type (got "object", expected "Union[int, str]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I figured that I can `cast` the return value of `one_of` at each of its call sites, but is there another way to better use the typechecker?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but check out discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452652/why-does-mypy-infer-the-common-base-type-instead-of-the-union-of-all-contained-t

Comment: A yucky solution would be to use `@overload` and a bunch of `one_of(arg0: T0, arg1: T1) -> Union[T0, T1]` overloads up to an arbitrary number of arguments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is "better", but mypy only uses `object` because it's chosen not to default to `int | str`. So you could tell it to use `int | str`. Just hinting one is sufficient

```
def int_or_str() -> int | str:
    one: int | str = "one"
    return one_of(1, one)
```

There may be a neater way of writing that.