# Mypy error - incompatible return value type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, union-types

Just started to use mypy, encountered a `Incompatible return value type problem` on a case that I considered correct, minimal example as follows:

```
from typing import Union

class A:
    def __init__(self, element: str):
        self._element = element

class B(A): ...
class C(B): ...
class D(A): ...

def run(value: bool) -> Union[C, D]:
    test = (
        C("foo")
        if value is True
        else D("bar")
    )

    return test  # error: Incompatible return value type (got "A", expected "Union[C, D]")  [return-value]

def run_2(value: bool) -> Union[C, D]:
    return (
        C("foo")
        if value is True
        else D("bar")
    )  # success: no issues found
```

I expected this simple example to work.
I used `mypy=1.0.0`.

Is it expected? Did I do something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that the value assigned to `test` is not *immediately* tied to the return type of the function, and that type inference prefers a more general type to a `Union`. [This](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_inference_and_annotations.html#context-in-type-inference) implies that the type inferred for `test` is not affected by the later `return test` statement.

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate, but https://stackoverflow.com/q/57452652/1126841 is relevant.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of mypy? try running `pip3 install mypy --upgrade`

Comment: Maybe the classes C and D are actually equal to A? Have you tried changing their definition more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mypy` can get confused when types get complicated, in these cases we have to write type hints for it manually, even if it is a bit annoying:

```
from typing import Union

class A:
    def __init__(self, element: str):
        self._element = element

class B(A): pass
class C(B): pass
class D(A): pass

def run(value: bool) -> Union[C, D]:
    test: Union[C, D] = (
        C("foo")
        if value is True
        else D("bar")
    )

    return test  # ok

def run_2(value: bool) -> Union[C, D]:
    return (
        C("foo")
        if value is True
        else D("bar")
    )  # success: no issues found
```

This is checked without issues by `mypy`